# Reduce JS object array with same DateTime into new object array with new fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I'm having JS object array

```
var data = [
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",
        "TagValue": 0.28503300001757387,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",
        "TagValue": 0.3287246675158156,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",
        "TagValue": 0.5102929393885312,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:05:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",
        "TagValue": 0.839778175550664,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:05:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",
        "TagValue": 0.6645055040936911,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:10:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",
        "TagValue": 0.7310429668316368,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:10:00+00:00"
    },
    {
        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",
        "TagValue": 0.7307108255629555,
        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:15:00+00:00"
    }
]
```

I want to reduce this array and change property response in such a way, if `TagName` has `ProfileFactor` it should represent as `x : TagValue` and if `TagName` has `Symmetry` it should represent as `y: TagValue` and combined with similar date time

expected output

```
result = [{
    "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:00:00+00:00",
  "x": 0.28503300001757387,
  "y": 0.3287246675158156
}, {
    "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:05:00+00:00",
  "x":0.5102929393885312,
  "y":0.839778175550664
}, {
    "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:10:00+00:00",
  "x":0.7310429668316368,
  "y":0.6645055040936911
}]
```

Comment: what happen when timestamp 2022-11-01T00:15:00+00:00

Comment: It will ignore as it just has 1 parameter and missing another one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `reduce` and `filter`. In the reduce step groups by timestamp to an object of timestamp as keys and then converts to an array of the values for each key.
Next filter the elements having both `x` and `y`

I could have used `.filter(({x,y}) => x && y)` but it would then exclude if both x and y happen to be 0

```js
var data = [    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",        "TagValue": 0.28503300001757387,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:00:00+00:00"    },    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",        "TagValue": 0.3287246675158156,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:00:00+00:00"    },{        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",        "TagValue": 0.5102929393885312,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:05:00+00:00"    },    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",       "TagValue": 0.839778175550664,       "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:05:00+00:00"    },    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.Symmetry>",        "TagValue": 0.6645055040936911,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:10:00+00:00"    },    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",        "TagValue": 0.7310429668316368,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:10:00+00:00"    },    {        "TagName": "<DanPac_A>.<Daniel.DanOPCHub>.<FT35101A.Blocks_127.ProfileFactor>",        "TagValue": 0.7307108255629555,        "TimeStamp": "2022-11-01T00:15:00+00:00"  }]


const res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{TagName,TagValue,TimeStamp}) => {
  acc[TimeStamp] ??= {TimeStamp}
  acc[TimeStamp][TagName.includes("ProfileFactor") ? "x" : "y"] = TagValue
  return acc
},{})).filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('x') && obj.hasOwnProperty('y'))

console.log(res)
```